# Send user auto generated password on different email

Tags: users, user-registration, email, password, email-verification

On one of my websites, I'm trying to customize different email content like user activation email/new user registration email.

Basically, on the activation email, it sends an activation link with the username & an auto-generated password but I want to alter the functionality a little bit.

On the activation email: it will send the activation link, nothing else.
On the next email/registration email: it will send the username, auto-generated password etc.
I want to move the auto-generated password on the second email instead of the first email.

I placed `$user_pass` on the second email but that doesn't work.

Hopefully, that is understandable. Any kind of guideline or help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: When does the second email get sent - after the user has clicked the activation link, or at the same time? If it's later then you'll no longer have the password available, no, but then no-one will have used the old one either: I think your best bet is to generate a new password then and reset the user's password at the point you send the second email.

Comment: Or if you are sending them both at the same time then you should have the password available. If that's the case can you show us the code you're trying to use?